# How to pass context of Scaffold to some function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button, snackbar, scaffold

I want to show Snackbar using the floating action button but I am not able to pass the context of scaffold as parameter to call the local function in onPressed argument.

Is there any way to show the scaffold using floating action button?

```
void main() {
BuildContext context;
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: "Exploring UI Widgets",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("My App")
        ),
     floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
       child: Icon(Icons.add),
       onPressed: (){
       //  showSnackBar(/*Here*/);
       },
       tooltip: "Floating Button",
     ),
      )
    )
  );
}

void showSnackBar(BuildContext context){
  var snackbar = SnackBar(
      content: Text("You just tapped Floating Button & This is Snakbar"),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: "Button",
        onPressed: (){
          //Blank Anonymous/ Lambda Function
        }
      )

  );
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly using `ScaffoldMessenger` inside `MaterialApp` will show context issue. Separate the home part.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'List Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: HomePage());
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  showMySnackBar(BuildContext context) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("data")));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("My App")),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          showMySnackBar(context);
        },
        tooltip: "Floating Button",
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          showSnackBar(context);
        },
        tooltip: "Floating Button",
      ),
    );
  }
}

void showSnackBar(BuildContext context) {
  var snackbar = SnackBar(
      content: const Text("You just tapped Floating Button & This is Snakbar"),
      action: SnackBarAction(
          label: "Button",
          onPressed: () {
            //Blank Anonymous/ Lambda Function
          }));
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
}
```